# Image Clustering by date and location

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, python, dbscan

I have Latitude ,longitude and timestamp of image. I want to cluster these image according to detect events. For instance I went to Paris for 4 days then london 3 days and so on. So I want to detect cluster of Paris data and after london.I want each event to be seperated. How can I use this Latitude ,longitude and timestamp together to make cluster? I have done with DBSCAN algorithm but could note merge the time in it.Look at popular Gboeing code if it helps to understand problem.

[image]

I have CSV file in my code which contain following thing ,lon,date,city,country
51.4812916,-0.4510112,05/14/2014 09:07,West Drayton,United Kingdom

Comment: I know that this code comes [from a very popular blog post](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/). But that doesn't mean this is good code... (`min_samples=1` means that you aren't doing DBSCAN, but it's effectively single-linkage clustering, why use geopy.distance when you have haversine in sklearn already, etc.) but because you copied the code, you should at least attribute it correctly...

Comment: @Viral If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Comment: @kadiologist Thank you for your answer. It was helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem allows for a deterministic approach, because you know which places you went to and they're cleanly separated in space and time.

- For each area you visited, choose a pair of geographic coordinates, such as the coordinates of a major landmark or the center of the city.
- For each time you visited an area, choose a timestamp, such as the time midway between when you arrived and left.

Now loop through the images and assign each image to the area with the closest coordinates, using a simple measure of geographic distance such as great-circle distance. To disambiguate between multiple visits to the same area, assign the image to the visit with the nearest time; you can measure temporal distance by just counting the number of seconds between times.

Comment: I want each event to be separated. What if I went to same location after 30 days?This will then show my previous event and these event together. That is why time is important.

Comment: @Viral Please edit your question accordingly, then.

Comment: @kadiologist I apologise. I have now included full description. If it helps with code

Comment: @Viral I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach:

1. Cluster the data by haversine, as you already do.
2. For each cluster, *cluster only this subset* by time only.
3. Merge noise of all clusters.

Answer (score -1):

Use 3 dimensional points say $(x;y;t$) with $x$ and $y$ being latitude and longitude and $t$ is time. For example, if you use the Haversine distance $h$ on Earth, then you can combine it with time by a formula such as

$$d((x,y,t),(x',y',t'))=\sqrt{\left(\frac{h((x;y),(y,y')}{h_0}\right)^2+\left(\frac{t-t'}{t_0}\right)^2}$$

$h_0$ and $t_0$ are the scaling coefficients. You must choose them carefully. Assume 1 day is the average duration for a stay, and 10 kilometres is the average geographical range of a stay (and $h$ is expressed in kilometres). Then it makes sense using $t_0=1$ day and $h_0=10$ km.

A note about the choice of the clustering algorithms :

You want to use DBSCAN which is ok. KMeans wouldn't be a great choice since you don't know the number of clusters $K$.

I would recommend a [density based algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Density-based_clustering) (DBSCAN is one of them). Generally density based algorithms work as long as the dimensionality is small (3 is small) and the clusters look like "grapes".

My favourite is the [mean shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift) : the complexity is a bit more than KMeans : $\log(N)N^2$ instead of $\log(N)KN$ but still reasonable. There are variants that will make it more or less clever, more or less fast... (I know DENCLUE is an advanced mean shift for example).

Comment: @benoitScanchez I have used DBCAN algorithm. I have now included photo of my code. I was trying to include the third dimention that is time but I am not sure how to include and use it.

Comment: **Don't compute distance like that.** On latitude, longitude, time this is utter nonsense to do. On latitude and longitude you need to use Haversine distance (because Earth is not flat, you know), and 1 mile is not the same as one second. So your units will be completely messed up this way.

Comment: I've rephrased my answer using the Haversine distance. It requires that your implementation of DBScan allows using a custom metric.

Comment: @Anony I suspect everyone can agree that such calculations might be "nonsense" when interpreted as Euclidean distances--but in some cases they might actually be *useful* in statistical analyses.  That's really the question to address.

Comment: @whuber by now, it can be sometimes useful, but the first version did not, lacking any normalization or haversine.

Comment: @Anony : normalization was the last sentence in the initial version : https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/290992/revisions. But yes, it's clearer since my last edit.